# Find classes that have the same attributs in Spring project

Tags: java, spring, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, plugins

I am working on a project that contains a large number of classes. The problem is that there are some classes that have different names but contain same members.

Is there a plugin on vscode or intelij that can detect this situation?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Attributes in different classes are unrelated (unless these classes inherit from each other and the attribute shadows a base class' attribute, in which case the compiler should warn you).

Comment: we are multiple to work on this project , here is the scenario , we are working on creating API's from wsdl , so we use xjc to generate the classes from the wsdl and continue our work , but with time we disscuverd that xjc generate classes with sames attributes and different names , we want to track those classes to we can use them again , not creat new ones.

Comment: @hamza I submitted the request in GitHub, but I think as Robert
 said, it may not be beneficial to most people.

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA you can try using [Structural Search and Replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html) feature.

Comment: Structural Search and Replace feature solved the problem